# Do they show the rat on the floor in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

Do they show the rat on the floor in the scene where Harry looks for Peter in the third Harry Potter film when he sees him on the map?

Comment: Iirc, yes, but in a way that shows that Harry (and unknowing audience members) don't know.

Comment: @cde In what way?

Comment: @lars in that a rat scurried away in the barely lit edge of the screen and small rat noises. Very subtle. I'll see if I can find a YouTube video to confirm, but I'm not 100% so that's why I commented instead of post

Comment: Can you clarify this for people who may not know the ins and outs of the books? Presumably this is some kind of easter egg for readers of the book? Or what?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, it's an integral part of the movie. One of the characters can transform into a rat (Peter). Without going into much detail, Harry sees a person on the map, but is unable to visually identify the person (because he's currently a rat.) The OP is asking whether or not the rat was actually shown on screen or just implied.

Comment: @remyabel: Hmm okay. Seems like a big deal over nothing then?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It matters to OP, apparently, though it would be nice if s/he would tell us why it matters.

Answer (score 18):

I've rewatched the scene a number of times and it appears that there was no (real) rat visible in the scene. To back this up, you can see the report from the [American Humane Association](http://www.humanehollywood.org/index.php/movie-archive/item/harry-potter-and-the-prisoner-of-azkaban) which fails to mention this scene entirely.

This obviously doesn't remove the possibility that they added one in *digitally* and there are definitely rat *noises* in the background.

---

You may wish to note that there's no mention of a rat in the film's [script](http://e-card.51.net/movie.scripts/Harry.Potter/Harry-Potter-and-the-Prisoner-of-Azkaban.htm) and direction.

> Harry moves down a DARK corridor, map in hand, WAND AGLOW. In the
>   PAINTINGS he passes, the subjects SNORE
>
> SOFTLY.
>
> INSERT - MARAUDER'S MAP
>
> "Harry Potter" and "Peter Pettigrew" draw closer and closer.
>
> BACK TO SCENE : Harry squints toward the end of the corridor. Down at
>   the map. Pettigrew moves quickly down the adjoining corridor. Twenty
>   yards away. Ten. Only seconds away... Wand trembling in his hand,
>   Harry glances from the map to the dark corridor ahead, again and
>   again. Then... as the two DOTS are about to collide... he looks slowly
>   up... turns the corner... heart in his chest... and meets...
>
> HIMSELF
>
> ... reflected in a MIRROR. He BLINKS, startled, then glances back down
>   at the map. Pettigrew has moved past him. Confused, Harry wheels,
>   casts his wand along the walls.
>
> **VOICE (O.S.) :** *Watch it there, boy!*
>          Harry JUMPS. But it's only an OLD MAN in a PAINTING, scowling in the glare of Harry's wand light. On the map, "Pettigrew" continues
>   to move away. Harry makes to follow, then stops. HEARS FOOTSTEPS.